# Turning A Stacked List into workable data

Tags: python, excel

In Excel I have a list of names that in the cell appear stacked, and I want each name in its own column. I was thinking Python may be a good way to do this?

Example:

```
Joe Smith
John Hawk
Mike Green
Lauren Smith
```

One cell will look exactly like that, with each name on its line within the cell but all of the names contained in the cell. I have 50 cells each with 1-20 stacked names and I want to put each name in its own cell on a given row. So, in my example all of those names would occupy the same row but each would have their own column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using Python for this seems like overkill: can't you just use the `Text to Columns` converter?  Used to be in the `Data` group.

Comment: Yea, just use text to columns - set your delimeter to spaces - and you should be good to go. This is assuming you don't have any middle names(your middle names might be in the same column as some last names then depending on how your names are initally ordered in which case I would recommend a couple simple spreadsheet formulas).

Comment: @DSM the text to column converter doesn't work because it treats the spaces the same giving me a column for Joe, Smith, John, Hawk, etc.

Comment: text to columns will work if you set your delimiter to Alt+0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're set on using python, you could export your excel to csv.

Then using python you can open your csv using `csv` module (`csv.reader`): http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

from there you can iterate each row of your csv.

the first index of each row will contain a string of stacked names.

You can split the names into a list using `split` method.  From there you can write those values to an output csv as a row (using `csv.writer`).

Comment: I am open to other suggestions for it, I just could not get it done in Excel and was not sure of a better alternative

Comment: I don't know if python is the best way, but if I was using python, this is how I would do it

Answer (score 0):

if you're ok with doing it in excel, the following code should work for you:

```
Sub SplitCellsAndExtend_Old()
'takes cells with inside line feeds and creates new row for each.

Dim strCell As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        strCell = Cells(i, 1)
        j = 0

        Do While InStr(1, strCell, Chr(10)) > 0
            Rows(i + j + 1).Insert
            strCell = Right(strCell, Len(strCell) - InStr(1, strCell, Chr(10)))
            Cells(i + j, 1) = Left(Cells(i + j, 1).Value, InStr(1, Cells(i + j, 1), Chr(10)) - 1)
            Cells(i + j + 1, 1).Value = strCell
            Cells(i + j + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1)
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Next
application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your question wasn't clear at first, but since someone edited it, I think I understand what you want.

Assuming you are using Windows and you have access to notepad, and wordpad (these should be in your accessories folder - the same one as your calculator)

Highlight your cells and copy them - then paste them into a notepad document.

[image: FromExcel]
It should look like this:
[image: ToNotepad]
Then copy and paste what is in notepad and paste it into wordpad and it should look like this:
[image: ToWordpad]
Then in wordpad find and replace the quotation marks:
[image: FindAndReplaceQuotationMarks]
Then copy and paste that back into and excel and you should get what you want:
[image: BackIntoExcelResult]

It's kind of a weird way to do it - but it should work for you. I often find that running lots of types of things through this pipeline(or a variation of it) gets rid of unnecessary formatting items. So it is good for lots of things. Good Luck